# How to Display Date::DAYNAMES In Index View?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

When the User checks off in the **_form** the `:days` he's "committed to", I want his days to show up in the **index**, but currently when the User loads the index page `<%= habit.days %>` comes up blank and I see that when the User clicks submit that the checkmarks disappear.

**_form**

```html
  <%= f.label "Committed to:" %>
  <% Date::DAYNAMES.each do |day| %>
    <%= f.check_box :days, {}, day %>
    <%= day %>
  <% end %>
```

**index**

```html
<% @habits.each do |habit| %>
  <td><%= habit.days %></td>
<% end %>
```

Do I need to add code to the **controller** or **model**?

**controller**

```html
class HabitsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_habit, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @habits = Habit.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @habit = current_user.habits.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @habit = current_user.habits.build(habit_params)
    if @habit.save
      redirect_to @habit, notice: 'Habit was successfully created.'
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    if @habit.update(habit_params)
      redirect_to @habit, notice: 'Habit was successfully updated.'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @habit.destroy
    redirect_to habits_url
  end

  private
    def set_habit
      @habit = Habit.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @habit = current_user.habits.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to habits_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this habit" if @habit.nil?
    end

    def habit_params
      params.require(:habit).permit(:missed, :left, :level, :days, :date_started, :trigger, :action, :target, :positive, :negative)
    end
end
```

**model**

```html
class Habit < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 validates :action, presence: true
end
```

**db**

```html
class CreateHabits < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :habits do |t|
      t.string :missed
      t.datetime :left
      t.string :level
      t.datetime :days
      t.datetime :date_started
      t.string :trigger
      t.string :action
      t.string :target
      t.string :positive
      t.string :negative
      t.boolean :mastered

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

### UPDATE

Now the index views pulls out this with the answer below:

["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", ""]

How can we get it to look like this?

Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using `f.check_box` properly, that helper is designed to be used on a single attribute, not used in an iterator.

You probably want something like:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :days, Date::DAYNAMES, :downcase, :to_s %>
```

#### Update

After some comments and an update to the question I've added the following comment, I'm putting it up here so the answer matches the question:

Your migration shows that `days` is a `datetime` field, there's no way that an array of strings is going to work. To make this work (although perhaps this is not what you want, and will break other things?) you would need to convert that field into a `text` type, ie. `t.text :days` in your migration, and then use `serialize :days, Array` in your model to make a serialized field.

#### Another Update

If you check your logs then you'll see something like: `"Unpermitted parameter: days"` - this is because you need to specify anything that contains a sub-structure like an array or a hash, so instead of `:days` in your `habit_params` you need to have `:days => []`

Comment: Thanks smathy! But when I replace my code with yours I get this error message: undefined method `collection_check_box' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x007fcd4c9ba750>

Comment: Here's my last question to give more context: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28402293/how-can-users-select-days-of-the-week

Comment: Sorry, should have been `check_boxes`

Comment: Thanks that removed the error and makes the code neater, but unfortunately `<td><%= habit.days %></td>` still isn't doing the job to display the days.

Comment: No, the days are displayed by `collection_check_boxes` without the need for anything else.

Comment: Oh sorry, you mean in your `index` - do you have a working `days=` method in your `Habit` model? Ie. does it work in the `rails console` if you do: `h = Habit.create days: [ 'monday', 'tuesday' ]; h.days` ?

Comment: I added the model above. You think I need to add something? I copy & pasted `h = Habit.create days: [ 'monday', 'tuesday' ]; h.days` and got this:   (0.1ms)  begin transaction (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
 `=> ["monday", "tuesday"]`

Comment: Ok, so the output just didn't pass the validation, but your model doesn't show any code that looks like it is ready to accept the `days`, where/how is that being stored in your DB?

Comment: Thanks so much for your patience I added the code above.

Comment: Your migration shows that `days` is a `datetime` field, there's no way that an array of strings is going to work. To make this work (although perhaps this is not what you want, and will break other things?) you would need to convert that field into a `text` type, ie. `t.text :days` in your migration, and then use `serialize :days, Array` in your model to make a serialized field.

Comment: I gave it a try and now the index shows: [] , instead of listing out the checked off days.

Comment: Also why do it as a `text` instead of a `string` since that's what it's an array of? We are almost there please don't give up on me now.

Comment: Because the array itself needs to be stored, not the strings, and `serialize` takes the array and turns it into a big chunk of YAML that could easily outgrow a string field in the DB.  Also, I updated my answer again with another problem you have in your code.

Comment: Awesome! One last question above, promise smathy! You have been a wonderful help.

Comment: `habit.days.map { |d| d.titleize[0,3] }.join ', '`